# performSegueWithIdentifier produce no segue with identifier error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am having hard time getting performSegueWithIdentifier to work.
I keep getting

```
"Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x1e59a9d0>) has no segue with
 identifier 'identA'"
```

What I did is that:

1. Step: created a single view application and added a label - "View controller A" to the view controller.
2. Step: Dragged and dropped another View Controller and added a label - "View controller B" to the new view controller.
3. Step: Chose view controller A and performed Editor->embed in->navigation controller
4. Step: wired View controller A to View controller B with push segue with Identifier "identA" Like this:
   [image: wiring the seque]
5. Step: added a call to performSegueWithIdentifier onView controller A's ViewDidLoad. Like this:

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identA" sender:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

What have I done wrong???

Comment: Without looking at anything to check up on, I believe you are supposed to call `[self performSegue...]` rather than `[self.navigationController perfo...]`

Comment: Sometimes it is the simple things we don't think about

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on `self.navigationController` but you setup the segue on `View controller A`:

> wired View controller A to View controller B with push segue with
>   Identifier "identA"

Try replacing:

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identA" sender:self];
```

with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identA" sender:self];
```

Comment: But how do you popViewController when you do this?

Comment: @stefanB, what would the swift 2.0 equivalent be? this: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);

Answer (score 4):

Just another suggestion (which saved me today)...

I've written many iPad & iPhone apps before, using Master-Detail pages, Navigation Controllers, etc, but today, I was stumped, as my simple two-screen iPhone app in XCode 5.1 refused to let me segue from one screen to another, within a UINavigationController.

It's another of those insane XCode bugs which made no sense.  I could even create a *new* XCode project, and there, the same segue would work perfectly.

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTest" sender:nil];
```

Eventually, I found out the cause.

I had created a blank project in XCode, manually added a Storyboard to my project, but, I'd missed a step.

When you add a Storyboard yourself, you also need to go into your .plist file, and manually add a line telling your app the name of your main storyboard.

[image]

If you don't do this, strangely, your app *will* build successfully, it *will* run, you'll probably get your first screen to be displayed successfully... but then things (like finding segue names) will start to go wrong.

(Sigh.)

I hope this helps other XCode victims.

I need a beer...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Bit of a particular situation here, but in my situation I had a `UISplitViewController` set up in a new project. I wanted to perform a segue in the detail view controller after pressing a cell in the master table view. So in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of the master table I performed

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"userDetails"
                                                           object:nil];
```

and in the detail view in `viewDidLoad:` I added the observer and the instance method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(userDetailsShow)
                                            name:@"userDetails"
                                          object:nil];
-(void)userDetailsShow{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userDetails" sender:nil];
}
```

When pressing the cell in the master view it would fire the method but do nothing. It turned out the problem was this:
[image]

I had left the default segue between the master table view cell and detail navigation controller active. In this case I didn't need it, so was able to delete it. Once deleting it it worked perfectly, as it should.
Hopefully I can now put this hair back in...