# "Has no segue with identifier" error occurs only when performSegue is called on `tableView (_: didSelectRowAt:)`

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue, xcode10.1

I'm struggling the whole day to fix "has no segue with identifier" error and got stuck.

**Error message:**

```
SegueTest[41862:1585831] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Receiver (<SegueTest.TableViewController: 0x7feed6510260>) has no segue with identifier 'tableToCollectionSegue''
*** First throw call stack:
```

**Related files getting error:**

Please check my `Main.storyboard` on GitHub.

[Xcode project files on Github](https://github.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest)

[Segue diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueDiagram.jpg)

[Capture of segue configuration for ViewController ( Working)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueOnViewController.png)

[Capture of segue configuration for TableViewController (❌ Getting error)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueOnTableViewController.png)

**Environment:**

- macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- Xcode 10.1
- Swift 4.2

**What I did in Main.storyboard:**

1. Created `UINavigationController` as an initial view controller and connect to `RootViewController` as a root view controller
2. Create `UINavigationController` that opened from `RootViewController` as a modal view
3. Connected the `Open Modal` button with the modal `UINavigationController` and named it `navigationSegue`
4. Create `ViewController`, `TableViewController`, and `CollectionViewController`
5. Connect the modal `UINavigationController` with the `ViewController` as a root view controller
6. Connect the `ViewController` with the `TableViewController` as a triggered segue (manual) named `viewToTableSegue`
7. Connect the `TableViewController` with the `CollectionViewController` as a triggered segue (manual) named `tableToCollectionSegue`
8. Connect the the `Next` Button on the `ViewController` with `@IBAction func didTapNext(_ sender: Any)` declared in `ViewController.swift`

**How the error occurs:**

When I called `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in [`ViewController.swift`](https://github.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/blob/master/SegueTest/ViewController.swift), it works.
([Segue capture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueOnViewController.png))

```
// Go to TableViewController
@IBAction func didTapNext(_ sender: Any) {
    //  Working
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewToTableSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

When I called `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in [`TableViewController.swift`](https://github.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/blob/master/SegueTest/TableViewController.swift), it got the error.
([Segue capture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueOnTableViewController.png))

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    // ❌ The segue `tableToCollectionSegue` is connected
    //    from `TableViewController` to `UICollectionViewController`,
    //    but got error.
    //
    // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    // reason: 'Receiver (<SegueTest.TableViewController: 0x7feeea04a090>) has no segue with identifier 'tableToCollectionSegue''

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tableToCollectionSegue", sender: nil)

    // ❌ The segue `tableToCollectionSegue` is not connected
    //    from `UINavigationController` to `UICollectionViewController`.
    //    This error is expected.
    //
    // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    // reason: 'Receiver (<SegueTest.TableViewController: 0x7feeea04a090>) has no segue with identifier 'tableToCollectionSegue''

    // self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tableToCollectionSegue", sender: self)
}
```

**What I have read:**

- [performSegueWithIdentifier has no segue with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27889645)
- [Receiver has no segue with identifier error message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33057818)
- [performSegueWithIdentifier produce no segue with identifier error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19040941)
- [Segue Error : ViewController has no segue with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36946528)
- And more

**What I have tried:**

- Make sure the segue identifiers are correctly specified and actually connected
- Reset all simulator settings and contents
- Clean Xcode Build Folders and `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` directory
- Rename Storyboard
- Restart and rebuild Xcode project
- Restart Mac

Comment: In my case, it is not an unwinding issue, and I've already tried deleting, renaming, and recreating the segue. It did not help.

Comment: I set segue identifier for TableViewController.  ([Capture Image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BillGatesFanboy/SegueTest/master/SegueOnTableViewController.png)) Could you answer more concretely?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following lines from `TableViewController`:

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(style: .plain)
}
```